# How to click an image in selenium webdriver using onclick with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an Image Refresh button in a same frame under two tables with same Img source and class name but onclick is different for the Refresh buttons.
This is the HTML coding for Refresh buttons. 
For the first refresh button:

```
<SPAN class=AddNew onclick=fnRefreshCAStatus();>
  <IMG src="../../SWB/BulkUpload/Images/refresh.gif"> Refresh</SPAN>
```

For the second Refresh button:

```
<SPAN class=AddNew onclick=fnGetCAAttributeCount()>
  <IMG src="../../SWB/BulkUpload/Images/refresh.gif">&nbsp; Refresh </SPAN>
```

Please help me to proceed.

Comment: provide some HTML code for analyzing

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would define (differing) `id` attributes for both spans and then do

```
WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
driver.findElement(By.id("firstSpan")).click();
```

If you leave the HTML as is (which I wouldn't recommend), you would do

```
int index = 1; // for the second span
WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
driver.findElements(By.className("AddNew")).get(index).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Xpath indexing. Like,

Fist find all the refresh buttons on the page with,

```
List<WebElement> refreshBtn =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Refresh']"));
```

Then if you want to click first refresh button use,

```
refreshBtn.get(0).click();
```

if second,

```
refreshBtn.get(1).click();
```